# open webpage in silverlight web application

Tags: c#, google-maps, silverlight-4.0

I'm working on the silverlight web application. i need to implement the google map so i prepare the one webpage in that i write almost code to load the google map and it work fine. now i want to open this page inside the silverlight.

> i try to implement the browser control but there is limitation of
>   browser control that we can't use the browser control in siliverlight
>   web application.

is there any way to achieve this?

OR

is there any other way to implement the google map into silverlight web application.

Comment: I would recommend using the Silverlight Bing Maps control, with the tile-source set to Google Maps. This will give you the maps you desire, via a proper Silverlight control. You can find out about how to provide a custom tile source from Google here:

http://www.scottlogic.co.uk/blog/colin/2011/02/google-sky-on-windows-phone-7/

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by using telerik RadHtmlPlaceHolder control, that can load .aspx, .html pages.

You just need to create a .aspx file that will load Google Maps using javascript api and call that .aspx file from silverlight telerik RadHtmlPlaceHolder.

Have a look for telerik RadHtmlPlaceHolder control

http://www.telerik.com/products/silverlight/htmlplaceholder.aspx